# DialogFlow Webhook API V2 - How to get Authorized User's accessToken?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

In my DialogFlow V1 Webhook, I used to get the user's access token like this (node.js):

```
exports.voxGoogleHomeWebhook = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {    
  const app = new WebhookClient({request: req, response: res});    
var accessToken = app.getUser().accessToken
```

This does not work in DialogFlow V2.  `getUser()` is not available on instance of WebhookClient.

I can not find in their documentation, how to get the accessToken of the Logged In user:
https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment

I tried getting app.session, but that's just the unique session string Identifier of the user's session.  It's not their access token.

How can I get the accessToken in V2?

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: @Prisoner dialogflow-fulfillment :  their go-forward beta v2 library.

Comment: And are you trying to get the user information sent by the Google Assistant? (You tagged it google-home, but I want to be sure.)

Comment: @Prisoner i am using DialogFlow into Actions on Google.  I am not using Android’s Assistant.  I am using the Actions on Google simulator and the Google Home mini device to test this.  Webhook deployed on GCP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the portion of the request object that contains this info isn't (yet) handled by the library. I've opened [a bug on the issue](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/14), and you may wish to follow or comment on it.

In the meantime, you can access the user information by looking at the `req.body` object. Specifically you can look at `req.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.user` to get the [User object](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest#User). The `accessToken` field there is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks.  In my case it was in: req.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.user.accessToken.     I am using Auth0 as the provider.   Perhaps you can ammend your answer with my path as well, and we will accept the answer.    I found it by inspecting the contents of the JSON object: 
 originalDetectIntentRequest.

Comment: Whoops! Was a cut and paste error on my part. Fixed.

Comment: With the dialogflow-fulfillment version 0.3.0-beta.3 , it is var accessToken = app.conv().user.access.token;
https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation.access.html#token